# Почему может не работать Log.d(...) при работе с Android-устройством?

Tags: android, android-studio, логирование, android-adb, logcat

Я пишу приложение в Android Studio, тестирую и отлаживаю его на нескольких разных устройствах. В нужных местах кода я вызываю метод `Log.d(…)`, т.е. приложение периодически что-то должно писать в лог.

На большинстве устройств всё работает так, как должно, – в logcat я вижу свои логи. Но на 2-х устройствах мои логи не выводятся. Системные логи присутствуют, а моих нет.

Настраивал фильтры по-разному, переподключал и перезапускал всё что можно, отладка на устройствах разрешена. Гугл не спасает. Устройства – смартфоны с Android 6.0 или 4.4.

Есть идеи, в чём может быть проблема?

***UPD:*** Обнаружил, что не выводятся только логи уровня DEBUG или VERBOSE. Если вызывать методы `Log.e()` или `Log.i()`, то всё работает. Пробовал принудительно задать уровень логирования (как указано в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#isLoggable(java.lang.String,%20int))) в терминале:

```
$ setprop log.tag.myTag DEBUG
```

и в коде:

```
System.setProperty("log.tag.myTag", "DEBUG");
```

но результат не меняется.

Comment: в build.prop не прописано, что не логировать ничего?

Comment: @VAndrJ ничего относящегося к логированию там не нашёл; сами файлы не редактировал, девайсы нерутованные

Comment: проблема запросто может быть в девайсах, у меня на моем meizu логи приложения не выводятся, есть только системные

Comment: У меня то же самое на Huawei Honor A6

Comment: А какие у вас устройства? Я помню в инженерке логи включал на LeEco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, является ли это решением. Но с тех пор я использую только вызовы Log.i(…). Пока что это ни разу не подвело меня.